# How to Upload Private Framework on app store in ios

Tags: ios, app-store

My question is i want to upload my app on app store in which my app contain private framework.So suggest me how to upload my app on app store with private framework with any restriction.

Comment: What do you mean by private framework?

Comment: elaborate private framework in Question ...

Comment: i am using bluethoot, IOSsurface & spring board.

Answer (score -1):

You can use appscanner  and see if it show any uses of any private frame